# Spring POST multipart/form-data Request empty body, getParts always empty

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, http-post

I need your help. I am implementing the server part of an RESTful WebService with Spring 3.
Unfortunately I have no influence on how the requests were sent, so no way to change that.

I want to receive an http post request as multipart/form-data.
I've an @RestController and did a @RequestMapping .. the request arrives in my method

```
@RequestMapping(value = BASE_URL, method = RequestMethod.POST, params = {"create"}, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void post HttpServletRequestWrapper request) throws Exception
```

I hoped that I can use the `request.getParts()` method to retrieve all parts. This is not possible, there are always no parts available. I think I figured out why: from the client no name attribute is specified for that part. I tried this with a RestClient on my Mac (Paw). When I leave the Part Name field blank, the getParts() method always returns an empty collection even if a file is set as value.

**My first question is there any possibility to use these Parts without a Part Name?**

---

Then, when the Spring PartResolver cannot handle the job I'll do it on my own.
So I thought I can parse the RequestBody myself. The problem is that the `request.getInputStream()` is not "accessible". Meaning, that `read()` always returns -1. When debugging I see that the Stream has a size, so I guess that the stream has been already read by Spring.

**My second question is, how can I access the post request body to parse it myself?**

---

Here is an example HTTP Request.
This request only contains one part. As you can see the header "name" for the part is missing. That's why Spring doesn't make is accessible via the `getParts()` method of the request.

```
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/2.2.5 (Macintosh; OS X/10.11.1) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 19691

--__X_PAW_BOUNDARY__
Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="Invoice.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

%PDF-1.2
%Çì¢
6 0 obj
<</Length 7 0 R/Filter /FlateDecode>>
stream
x5A
0ïyEÎb¶i½ûûQñ ¢þlYY&»abCvýË|À}¸= ¸µÙA% $.ÑÜ«æH    ïÖ¸]_Î3ïrW1²/©ÿÑ×ã   SÓÌXendstream
endobj
7 0 obj
105
endobj
9 0 obj
<</R4
4 0 R>>
endobj
10 0 obj
<</R8
8 0 R>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<</Type/Page/MediaBox [0 0 595 842]
/Rotate 0/Parent 3 0 R
/Resources<</ProcSet[/PDF /ImageB]
/ExtGState 9 0 R
/XObject 10 0 R
>>
/Contents 6 0 R
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages /Kids [
5 0 R
] /Count 1
>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<</Type /Catalog /Pages 3 0 R
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Type/ExtGState/Name/R4/TR/Identity>>
endobj
8 0 obj
<</Subtype /Image
/ImageMask true
/Width 2366
/Height 3069
/BitsPerComponent 1
/Filter /CCITTFaxDecode
/DecodeParms <</K -1
/Columns 2366
>>
/Length 18410>>stream
ÿòÕòÝ£Æn?£¹FyB1Ñ:!ç!GDHDr0!´{6ò:8Ì"N#äp0G0Ü
ÅÄ/Ñæ^=©c0!HÃ(ÌDDDJÓ#(3Hàt! °VdÔ k¹FëHlã.aÈ-XåRâÑ,¨økEÑ)Ë£ ´GEÑ!Ñ~/"è¾mÑ|Â&qp<Hñ¸DDáHèÈDUFÂ.ñ9â>"[§
ÄDDDDDDDDDDDDI°²þZ£ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿËYZ<£ÊZÕÈ4h3q·µ´ï_ú§ïö±pG¹!É±÷º{ùïÅÜZL¼K"Yfãyf©eÑ²£¥×NóùféÁ¨'@yf,áG$8a¦LÛBõ'ºÍ§ D °2âäÈ%ä&r¾..Èþe#hù«4
r-_xDv0`×Uñ¬!A"$AË)a¸AyøkÈAÊª£¤$ð=a  5N$(  QN
dAÊ«=¹ÈR(¡ÞÕF>ý÷!K«þkB">¶¬5S°A"Payqú~¾EÞàèi0Ð;Ò´DÙ+hØA§{!Ä]Ù)!f6`Ö[Dà6ÉcDµ¢bÎ@ÛmIwÊz3.f À94"æ³@´èMðA¸A´¬Ýá%
¿KÃ`°Á¸=$H@xxM¨0Ûum/nß 
ùrnAÇ»Wr,ì6óÂH7m«ÐmÛ§ômëH ßÐÇtOG}z &ß¯nÿIöÛô¾!°è0Ûð}$ÿí·¥þÛ~7ä#¡"=Óa¿ô    ×ý¶ßÿ
¿Tðß@8   Â2
¿
xaágÿ¶m¿Òol0üI¿  !¸iÝÁ=ÿ$ÿ½ÿô½úI¿
#*$ý²á}¶ý#úßþÕÿþÚáU¿&?i.8lÿõOÿÛéíü*üPNcS°ÿö·ßÚ·÷þßªWpÄUºû¿ú¥{ÿ¿ïýý+IÁ!)òÇ×Ýüu»ýß§ÿÚ×ãX·÷ýÕ+ÿÝ__Mô½ð~÷ÿÛÿóiÿÿ¶þ]S_×õÞ¿û¿ÿí¿÷¢CÑlûkKßõÛýÛú_©Âl3yÈçO¾5Mÿúl?ÿí·õìEñqØ&÷þ¿ý«¿ÿý®<22ä`6A$Lp×¥Lï
÷ÿ^?Kad6Ç¡qßÿ¥ÿüã¶ÿûñ¡¤¿¥þ¾Ûÿí·õT÷ÿ9-ÿkÛoÿý»ÿÈ
þ¿ÿ~Ûÿí·v¾?ÒûKÿmý×ý·ê½úþ¿ÿ÷ÿîÿ¥
ýÿÿßÕÿÛnµ|àaÃõKÕRþ¿oõÿÛú\XäHäßô«õÿ~íÿÿ·wýÚ ~_ÿÿ¶÷íÿ·oBMÉF:BLr1þ>ÿþÜ>Ý/öÛZü@é   rCÀã½Kë_ÿÛz¥ÿí¿ò,
V"""!"?¡ù]%úûl;ÿü6ßª§dÇ   |$¿áÕm¾ûÿ¶ÞþBWÈãü.¿â#þÛëöÛëú§öaÂìÿ^oÛÿá·¯Á¸¢ÄB4¹Ua_í×¯ý°ïèäüÌ."E§ðÏânF:õvïëýß¾Ãu(ì·(pPZþ?vï÷ÿî¸Ðë¿õýÝWÿ¶ßNíÕô7ærW¿ÿý»ÿü;¯¯ßM¾A¿ùí¿ÿûnÿé~Lr·íÿïûo·ÿöß{ÿá{ûÿÒý»¥×ýïÿáwmýÿýÛ¿ÿö×ÿúÝÿÿÿm×¿ûÿÿöa¿}¿ÿ
ßÿøm¾¿¾ïÿÿ¶ßZÿí÷ÿ}+vÿÿ¶ûÛÿa¶×¿ÿ{ÿÿý·ëÿÛ~»ÿì0ß×þÛ¾¿Ý»¶ÿbPPdãýÿ}ÿþßûÿ¶Ö¿åUÑ¢$³þßÅ¿ÿÃÝ×_íßíü²-!¶æd
ÎPå9C©78å97$äËÂ°®÷oÿÿ[oÿý¶;¿äØ0×[    â""""""?»ÿû¶Å}¥ûµ÷ùI»0á~ïîÿý·ÿýõoøuÿÛýßßöÛßÿm»vÿL ï÷oïÿ÷ûoýÚÛÿwÒ}í¿ Ûÿöi¿ÒöÿÃ«5m¿   ¶ÙUþâ¾¿¶;ïïõnÿ¿ÿö÷ÿÛÝ¿Þ©ÿÛý;kÿí÷ëíí¿ýpávÛo×Òõýþúÿïÿhßô÷êÛkÿöû¥ýöÿ½4Ca$×í¿Ón¿ÿuú^ÞÝßïa<® Èdpxl!£:Ûöõí§é~ÞÛÁwêÜDa;{õß¯¿o¿K¶öÛý«ûmú,tÛ$þÞíÿ¾Ûÿ}Rþíþ¶í/ÿwnÒý½úûúWÿ»mý+Ú×þÚ¶áRööØßZ|>¾íúUl4¿þë¸I}í°ÿçiÇ@ä(wÕV¾Þ¸^m:ô¿owJ»oa¶¿È@ÎDÃFt
a°
ÀíÈ¨ÞþàÎ`H0Á!ý,7°ÃA%pÝ"èá~xNe®a¡ï¶ÝíXa°ÁR_¾Û¶Ø0H$Ý¶ÈB   }z    ý¨Ñ°MÉÁ1ÄkÜ>Â    ØdAÊð«þï¶ÔU
Ûá3aBÐM=S'¢¿ÌDDim+»"GiXaXa&Þlá "=B.©øIÿÆ°ö%0Á `ÂPd1ÈNØa 00má4Õ4ô¤ÔÄ&¸FC(4ÙOà2Th0máAü$·AØ_I§ª¤d·hHÇ"@ðZ¦v¤1CH §I¶0ÃE@#ÂG14\*~©ûz zr9äãÞC`ä4Ü|p®ÁjACA\xb%¸¸1
«¤/ÄDDDDDhlDDS!H­ bNuÖâOKëÙÁ¬ îTÓ Ø"LÅÔÏoJA~ûòCPrNMÔrn@ð.9(&9är1Èw#rcRrPqÎ9!Èl¡È®Så¬  ½Y¨A´~Òò 3dIÄÇïílØÿzúýÚ~CÄDDDDIQÒAá7¥OÿÄEÊdsq:§®Ò¦äô·é2æ`Ì2äG"àx0\ÈáG"9.dp7#ÁÆG
tÝ<BI¸CMü·&äàÙ7.ËrwpîáÃ[Y8.p\¡Ë{@ÍfÃZø\ÜÜ&°ÓL~ë¦}/ìF×ÖÆ"""-$
ÐE8úp+A!hDDDC´aá àÃqÄEaíò-_ëöBº#³Øl;¢;l2Án#
¤ÈéZk.Úo1J `Á&%Õfß]Eªþýz×Syìæ{9G¼_oñÎg3Úgìæ{Læs=±öôÍÿ¿Ò^·ÿwwßÿßwÚ÷ÿ¯þÿ®«Þ©§ßýý~!¡hDDDZDZÈ4F8hî/_ÄDD¬"Zè¬¨qÿç&ÞeD{9G³ìæz7G³ìæ{9Îg³¸än9g#ös=ÎJyÎg³fãÈæs9ÎG$Óï÷ñïk}Ý§ßÿýÿÿýý¿}ÿÿûî×
¯k§°^úi ÕÐätÐ»TÐnAà\WÀ\Vp!wB j¥ïûý;1Hðá#ÂGÄ  8Ì3¸KÇ#È0ÄÌ0Â;>$vÃ;ah4Ðvi¦rAç ÍeÀ!#³
4¼Û7}¿µíõ»O´ÓMu]S]WMª½ªé®ëwÝÝÿï×ï]Wÿßwøï¿wÚ}ýúÿÿÐÝ®ØZpðDDP!øl>Ë³X0b"%!á a0aeÀ0a`Ã0b"9Ö1G
]ÉO9ä²wä4HrNHq&äI¦zj#GHDzÞªª¶ýÉ*ïMoðDG5wxéßñÿ÷ýñüôCÞ×¨PDaÂA
ø:ÿ"$$Ç!Dcúå<ý6Ù¨}°ÂÒ$äÇ#u   q&9î¡"nF98ROAUuprïÈpè<Î>Â²C²9hqDE§!uÐwUv¢.ØPiqST«Jÿ¶ÿ«F@ñ\`þ·ëNÚþÁ¶AònIÉ<$9äÇ#r1É¹CmÖÈÀo
XuðÒéØÙàó<9S)@â$QÏB¸§)AÒCÔ$ªIa(5Ý[ÄDDXÄDE/ãb»ÛvÝôÂkaµ¥þ½ÝjÛ    uÿ»þÒ_ØMvÂý÷è;[mi8`®¼&[ºÃý¶½°aSµh5¸auA«.ÊNPåá[+ªN9à²ÒÝ0ÓAÐ0BF"""""""0dÇ!ÎäÊH`¤Ù©Ò"1ZÄF<ÑGÿÿùjC#òÍ0!&ÈZ(Â&Ã5vC!ED
D)îÓ  ®«U ÚUZ­/¿ÿÒÿú¯Ú×¯Uúú¥¯¢r+ßq×ý®8i¡ê5XÒÌ¸r0e )PµjDKHêÌÌ!ó¦4 cÈ=f°À\ØB!)89Ô@3ãá4E0L õð¡©3DCAPh@´ÁºhXB½
5PÐi®ºú^Âë­Ri× ïÒMt>½z    úaz¦úzëþÿÿ­Ûô«¥]¥éH|¾8ùv¿ªuÈ8ÿ{¢¹8bAy§:£éHOÂ~=ÑnC´Ò½Î9Ç@ëAë^é>AºzúO!4½i=$,%áöëIëÕ$ZOUUZP®»úWOIZ__×Mt*Ha:õOÒO¯ÿJúúð°¡.ízZ°Uú¥ú×TÖB°q×ñ¥u¨ëÿ¾ºÀº[ÿK×_®©kþuÈ]kúN._ªJ«!ì§0Ä©aõþ_ê½}t#­PzõÿÈ?Zú®¿­`xK
×õªö«×ÿ¯ÖCÿPò#k¿¥úä áWþª¿ZAaý­uC­iköT©QHÿW­wêëÿýÕ%ÙAU4Þ²F«ÚÒ_aVµKA¾ôêðþ½÷õµKÿµU¾Â×ÒÒ_i´ëá®¾Úÿ Ë¾ÖþÖÖ[
ºÁ­Òë
U(Ð{Å}Â_U/#øÿÒIE1ÿ±\ú«ÖÿMui«M5^õ[J
B®ÓûízM}=oí¾ÕUu[îÕo» ïéÖ© ÿTV¾AãÔ:jA Âh4_&TÓ ­ Èi¦0A Î8!ÂÈCÇi¦a0A¦wAÍXhÑ
",¡ÊpDDb!! qt!&KAå²vvc)0XiÀy%A    IpáÆZf¨¯PCXYÁÓ>Y¡R"/GhA¦©§jA§cØL'¦°¡÷Á Â(Aí_}¦«~ß­®Wý¦ªqòðÂ¿äÊ!Ï÷

Âãÿ' IÂÓ¤"hûéÒM­?|¿z¿Òº~äd;¡cò ]ëÝwÿBóa¤|)ÔgA"8g¼ÌDý&×Ü Â    i¦a4þìÂj¾Õþiè=?Â
øõÄVB÷þN.!ük}kðºÿ¨AßÚß¶GÍ°_­Ë iwëôkPZÿ,wÆVE)R
UÁdzò?äò·íj;ÿ&Áa0A â¡6{rò   ÿõÈëK] geäðAOA<'§§ýÒ¿!ûZ_þOÂ
4¨=ß¿ ßíô0z_þ¯i¦mÓÿÓÿ^ÿµôÓTá~ÁW_µþßÃ×ÿêiÚýãÿë¥÷¯ÿ¾DÙëÝÂAÑt¿ÿ×ýÕHg¡ß_þúä$4BãD?j"?ÿÿ}ïºõßü­à·ÿÿÿcè²^A~õ oúé´'ÿÿÿýýKÿï÷¾û×°úÿÿý¯øh.ÿîj
:!3)áéÕ÷_ÿÿÿW´Â^¯Áa\
<'ëÿ{µÿö»ú·¥ÿêÓN4N/ýo|7"¤ÿÿÿÛþÒ®ûýNAqÝ§×ë¯ïD_ÿ¿µûa$·KK÷~©í¯ûyïÿþ×ûVÕ#æµµøM8Õ;þ×| v¿ÿúïÂÁ¢/´5úòOb½¿öí?×ð¾Ã[oNCã]?Útò22î¿ÿ¶öÒÿµøkÿK»[TBæG8dCh6v]uíÕ_ÛìtÿM}|$Ãþý­ÿ¼Sÿÿý5îÖÊé½­ëI­ûí[]½ÿúß§^¾×´ôõiá[k·TëýïºôÕí0½\1k
{ÓadnÒÿ× ÀÿúaVÓX[È:w-
R!q±±±íiÿï¼0^öC0h.A»¬"¬!V=VÈ1¢R ^Ð&ß}Ã  »áíS]M­¢èÂ#Â" Ïp¾¹¨66áÝ¦  aû¡0F¤$bÄDDDDG^ÃkúíH0=ÄA B"Dùåû~¿îÈ<C[ ÄEò(ß5×úÃkþü/û)õÞ ×øÿñQÇ`ÈáàÝè¡ù¯ý?â«yäDmÿ¬Ño}Aý%{þzþy½-zýéê½5[ }w_­­®W½öÂ¶ìI°aL(`»`°ÂßaX4½X0V*(
Ð¬lTwÅ1[CéþÚ÷z®õýU?i¯pÂö
5v}ê¶¦a5»!·¦= Ó;M4í0A`¢L'ÂÁ2bADDDGÿÿå¡/d¢6de È°(;9TC!¾wL(A¦wýAáýSAÚwõMl'Tí>ö«ª§!)Æ
´h6³h;£¨^&ÒzMï×}µn½ÍgC­]=uøD=EÙLÙ9©¶ÿÐh=;?é:í?§h^Dýb¯ ÿ½{}þ©'ýà¿¯¤ëøakÿu_øÿþ¶¸ä8ëÙï·ëè~ÿÿIªzôÿøI4õÿÿJëýÿÿé0Ó.¿Ò¿ÿé\Gþ×ÿõD)ÿ¿ÿÿV¨'ëÿÿÐXoúÿ_[ÿëß×¤¿ý_ëþ^¾õÿ{ª_"þ¿éÿ÷§«Ð_ÿÿí}öj¿ïßjÚIjØ@ÿÿi:V©júÿöÖØIlÂ_ÿa&
d3¿üqÅ'±]Úß§ûþîÒÂiúþÓUõÿö®ký®ÓA­ÂÝÚíB&`A¦a`¢!DGÿÿå$E¤ìH!P)H!T"H¹`XI7gj"¤!&)Èø"´
° ahN0jªeL)¥ ÈÀnk Ða
¡0A×A Ða¡4NÓON×áTÐzié¦i­¦Ó¸a4õO[»ONÓúa0¯kV÷§k}PiÓÂ!aÈä]©fÑ   ôEDt
"E¦E rl1Âè!3!3"sD'äG5ah&ô¥tûi$ûjñ
tðM¤îôÝtëïUÓtü'¦Õéá^Óz]=>ëû¤éIºuz½ê½òT]×ß×µÓï}_êÿ÷t¼9*ËÜ>_á¯ëå tûÿ¨küµñ÷ûñû_¶
-}~+Þkëí«úý_?ÇWþ«ým%ÕoõRè×ÿ ÿKïµSdúmûi}¥¥¿ý=&Ö­ûâþiVNÚM¬0Kÿßé{$ØJVÒðKãb%íý?Íaþ8ì¹4)n¾½®ÒÿèwøK°Â
 u|D:
¶þÂ
C»[_OÿÓM}}<WÃôÂr÷al/I¿ïÓNAÝø}¯¿AÜ{om}?÷é§"Mßá­ýþ©Ó²¢Ã
ØOÿíöÐvxux«^!¿04DÇMn8úÿa=4B»§ÝòÀõáýr
»^/öúDIº>#MþE)µíù°]Ý6.pwÿøo³a8îpü÷ôðêßmÈ0<?ÿM{nûÖ
ÿÿ]>®ÖÈaÿÿÿt¿ð¿¿ÚÚÿ°°Âÿû}^û{ÿªßoôÿ~
a¿ÿÿëÿý7^Ö¿ê±Ã*Öÿõÿÿèúý¯¯}Gò0=¤íÐdÇKþxñuÑD õ<TÝ
íçcëÿçÏñüóU^¸Kië¯Úª5>KÿÕm~ôé?ÿDAíýtõúWÝZUs[ÛJÒ×]+[«^&V¶·ÚW¶­þÐûu­ú¶·]­=¥kkjý«am-/k°Ö×[Ý&ë
Ø^Â­°ÖL:aØJÂÚM«kí}&Mm(al%iCK°Z¸ØeÂÃ#    A ã¨ã#ì0hpÂØXiA`ÁY
öÇ±¤í1±Lllm5X¦****)¯Jþ©¦ívôí;Óí«m4í5M4×kÝªzi¦¾¦jUOÿi í Ó[ Ä4­¦M®×µL&M;NÂi Ó4Â ÐiÁ¢¦a¨¤sÛ5Á$XD/#â"#ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿü¶TSÙËá?é¬·/®«ÓÙ@d]ö9ó¢'r:­îÓ4"FgÉLÐA¢)Â!Ð8ëäL Ð°!aa|^T]0°@ÉËïN-tì&S@côôþî×#iü¶¤qîE©åÑò1è÷¤ÝþpÂJä_ðO#ô/=UPà¿"C¯MxèBïQpc!è1Ý;üEúêÃ´ºØ_ý®ÿüÖÿ·õ¿ÿÿúm¿ÿ×!ÿ   ÞAÇ_ùVGV
ÿú:(  "úßß~púõôÏs| Ì×ýtÚw¬5VÂ
<&öDlÙßÈhËØV76;ÿuk]ª~+÷û}®¿"Óëím»N×I¾úÃ

; Âký¦N
4¾L¡ÍÁ8aræNqÁo§ïü2&
"#ÿùLÉ`å¶i¤o.D Ïs e@ï¹dZ+FUÐiÃÓ^ù7#àAÔ2
4Óáêÿpô¿½;þ°õ ÿÞõøxMu÷Hv·ÿ½4ÿä^r#2¨¨Èÿï¹þ¡IÊxç¯ò,d#~¾ýû` dpè$!ÞõïÃ¤è4X¿ø}]':xLÀ¿ÿc  wÿ¿tá&ï²»__5ÝþöGF"9A¯qû}{ÿâ"Ø?ã¿ýÈa"»ÿaò%·¯ÜyÓ¿ï¼z{ÿp{! Ï¯·ßMïú}¼¤ÓÂ
ëøo_ëýûxD1¯ÿöÿëþ
ëÓÓÖõ"þîFCÿA¿ÿä(çù  ¿ÿÿäA¿¯üþIá¶ÎoÿßZ
»¿ÿúàáÿÿ¯ä¤Kÿýuvï_ÿÕeA¾jÿþû×íoÿÿÿïúínûªý®»ö¿Ø[ÕÂ¯Ø[ÿ÷·ÿñRVÁ)ñ_ô·[ý¯õ±±úÿìðy9Ç*a×²8ÿëüqX)~+úÚÒÿûêµÿµ^ïþ
5»×¼áMS'`kÖÂaU°Ç@Â`DAÎ[ÂÝÿ#;B"!rf´ÂpÂ   Ða""1:!2(DËlÐW(
LÈÔY.ìì.!Ä¢5 É¸¼_;"²))¨R @ï
Wº    ºðPAþ*aS Âiá=NÔ.º®UíBwªªÞ×PÚ§n¿"Ä*õKÕSïþdXíakò$Sÿ:¢:Ê|åæ¡tþÕmÓÈ¼)R#@¥ÂsBÂkL,Gï"GÃý~f4ØÓA
~z#¦ªñîC2\_!5¯ßÃ÷ ïÕ5´ÆTWs@à@ÁaÃZÿ_øÂ~ª÷$û0ë!`Ð°1×õ¡è?¤ÐN©=S±"²ôïTõ^Ø ùÿHwMHHÔ)>¸Ç»®ºøY!þÒ­è&þBøAØ&
¨0¡_¥éô¤(îÞB=d8ôKµªvÿú¦ß]ß¿t4 ä[RA<   ¾¶7ÿPÿTÿ|A{×õMí4ï{´ö§{ð×ÿêCqòß®kÃJµö¾ïÅÿ¿lPZ¿®Ò·4¢\wWu)ÄïþúaÞ»wmÕp{@¿¡}ä[mì÷û~zë×ÁøUöÒMÕßªÿëo×¾¾Ý¿ÿ`­SýÿýíümÈqÌ9C_ÈAÉéVý_ô!3c¿ÞBYC9SÿÕ²ð]ïÂÃ~¿¾=~Õî­âéiù¥ÿÕû¿#ÿ8?óÇ¯zçÍ¿ýíÛ_x#{øWaVÌ
nÓUm¸8k°Â] ÃW°ÂåÉXklW´=úÚ~Úµ
t­]ØkWmoÿt£Õx§¶®ÿ¿jßßkÁ~Ackßªö½úkk±QPþ?iÿ^½¯i×Ú®½¿ûMW´û[µ»{MS^}Ú÷é¦·iðáÚi­¦Úí~Û^ÖÓA§h0"GaSAíi Â
9øh0Úé¦A¦Mè¾A# Á,"!àÌ8B!hDG´ÓT->ÃA!´`MAa¡ÿÿÿÿÿÿþS¤c#²SVF³%È¨"L
xd ÊÈIg[ÉGÉB ÁL0ØOü',YT"dB2!¢(1¬Aè4î×þMÅ8"%D@l0AéÞºv=4ÿ

[Generated code truncated to 10k characters, "Export" or "Open With" to get all code.]
```

Comment: Have you tried using `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile` as your method input? Spring will autoinject it. Your parameter name may vary, of course.

Comment: Yes I already tried that. I think the `RequestParam()` does expect the name of the part, right? And the name header for the part is missing. Even if this would be the filename header-body, the problem is, that I do not know the exact filename. There can be some parts with different filenames. Anyway, the filenames are given according to a particular pattern, but the filenames vary. So I think I cannot use a RequestParam with an fix filename.

Comment: You can try`@RequestParam` without a value. I just tried - it works.

Comment: Really, how did you managed that? How looks the request you send? I get an exception `org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException` with the message `Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present`. My request looks like the example above. From my point of view the problem is that the part does not contain any name header-body. I think Spring does expect here the name "file", right?

Comment: I see. Apparently, not specifying the value results in Spring defaulting to 'file'. I have `name = "file"` in my multipart file, so that works. I'll look into the code to see how Spring parses it.

Comment: Well, `MultipartFile` interface specifies that `name of the parameter (never {@code null} or empty`. :(

Comment: Hmm that's a pity. So no way to use the Spring MultiPartResolver? Is there a chance to overwrite that implementation? I am quite new to Spring and I do not know how to manage that ... Have you an idea why I cannot read the InputStream of the request? I think Spring has already read this, as I can see in the Debugger that the Stream has a size, but `read()` or something like that always returns -1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93779/discussion-between-ilya-novoseltsev-and-caldicot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parts without a `name` parameter are not being parsed by Tomcat (*question author is using Spring Boot with embedded Tomcat*). In fact, the whole body gets discarded if there is no `name`.

I see no easy or good solution. As a workaround you can override Tomcat's `FileUploadBase` class and implement a custom `getFieldName` method that will always return a non-null value. Since Tomcat is in your classpath, being embedded in Spring Boot, you will be able to override this class.

Comment: As described this solution works when using embedded Tomcat with Spring Boot. But using a external tomcat instance, it won't work, because the class will not be in the class path. Can anybody imagine a solution for traditional tomcat installation via war file?

Comment: This might be a change in behavior. I used what the OP does since spring-boot 1.5.x. Recently upgraded to spring-boot 2 and parts is now empty. I did not change anything else other than to update the dependencies to make it build and compile.

This is a little bit annoying, to say the least.