# Spring Boot, Jetty: Multipart upload - make Spring/Jetty accept body parts with missing "filename" attribute?

Tags: spring-boot, jetty, multipart

How to make Spring (or Jetty) accept/parse Multipart uploads where the body part(s) miss(es) the `filename` attribute in the Content-Disposition?

Otherwise than the missing `filename` attribute, the Multipart message is OK and it also used to work with an older version of Jetty/Spring.

What do I need to set to make Jetty/Spring a little more error tolerant again?

P.S.
Here I found a similar yet different problem (`name` attribute missing). Yet, while the `name` seems like a vital attribute to identify body parts, you do not necessarily need the original client-side filename: [Spring POST multipart/form-data Request empty body, getParts always empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33420389/spring-post-multipart-form-data-request-empty-body-getparts-always-empty)

Comment: Solution so far: Override Jetty's StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest class and reimplement its parseRequest method not to skip body parts when there is no file name.

Any other, better propositions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment:

Spring (4.3.8.RELEASE) unconditionally skips multipart files without a filename, i.e. there is no setting to make it more error-tolerant. Thus, the only solution was to override Spring's `StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest` class and modify the method in question: `parseRequest`.

The added lines of code:

```
if (filename == null && "file".equalsIgnoreCase(part.getName()) && MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getContentType())) {
    filename = DEFAULT_FILENAME;
}
```

And yes, the name of the multipart body part doesn't necessarily have to be "file" but this is the name the client application my code has to work with is using when uploading a file.